# Detect mobile phone presence with Bluetooth usb dongle.

Tags: node.js, mobile, bluetooth

I am using BeagleBone Black and Bluetooth USB dongle V4.0. My dongle is detecting iBeacons with no problems but is there any way to detect mobile phones with bluetooth on. I am using NodeJs and Noble package.

So when I use hcitool lescan it's not finding mobile phone either but with hcitool there is option scan. When I call hcitool scan in terminal I get my mobile as result. Is there any NodeJs package that wraps this option. I have no need to connect to mobile device, I just need to discover it's presence, and see it's MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

If you can see your device with "hcitool scan" and not with "hcitool lescan" it means your phone(or BT stack you use in phone) don't support BLE protocol. Not all BT devices are BLE capable.